# How to display two minipages containing unequal length listings side by side?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, minipage

I have two listings which are my Makefile sources. Some lines in this Makefiles are long. I need to fit them side by side in a particular location in my report. I tried to do something like this but I was not successful.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, titlepage]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./Figures/}}

\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
%\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
\usepackage{dirtree}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}

%to get clickable links from table of contents
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
\newcommand{\courierword}[1]{\textsf{\itshape #1}}{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont}%

\setlength{\parindent}{0.0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}

\setkomafont{sectioning}{\normalcolor\bfseries}
```

The actual content is as below

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\captionof{figure}{Makefile for 'aocs' Collection}
\lstset{language=make,
        commentstyle=\color{red},
        breaklines=true,
}
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single][t]
This section contains my Makefile 2
Some lines are really toooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo long
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\captionof{figure}{Makefile for 'aocsApFw' Constituent}
\lstset{language=make,
        commentstyle=\color{red},
        breaklines=true,
}
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single][t]
This section contains my Makefile 2
Some lines are really toooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo long
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Would a landscape page be an option? Or setting them on a left/right page pair? The bets font I found for long lines in listings was Latin Modern TT Condensed; that might help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some remarks to your code:

1. Your are using the listings option `frame`. Due to this your listings itself get wider. The new listings has the width:

   ```
   framerule+framesep+0.5\linewidth+framesep+framerule
   ```

   To take care of this you have to add the following option:

   ```
   xleftmargin=3.4pt,xrightmargin=3.4pt,
   ```
2. With the option `breaklines=true` listings can break to long lines. However the breaks occurs only at characters declared as `other`. The following table shows the default definition (see documentation)
   [image]
3. The environent `minipage` has an optional argument do adjust the vertical position. In Your case you can use `t`. Please note that caption needs the same amount of lines.

Here is the modication of your code with the result

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, titlepage]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./Figures/}}

\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
%\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
\usepackage{dirtree}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}

%to get clickable links from table of contents
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
\newcommand{\courierword}[1]{\textsf{\itshape #1}}{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont}%

\setlength{\parindent}{0.0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}

\setkomafont{sectioning}{\normalcolor\bfseries}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
\caption{Makefile for 'aocs' Collection}\par\strut
\lstset{language=make,breakatwhitespace=false,xleftmargin=3.4pt,xrightmargin=3.4pt,
        commentstyle=\color{red},
        breaklines=true,
}
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single][t]
This section contains my Makefile 2
Some lines are really tooooooooooooooo ooooooooooooooooooo long
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
\caption{Makefile for 'aocsApFw' Constituent}
\lstset{language=make,,xrightmargin=3.4pt,,xleftmargin=3.4pt,
        commentstyle=\color{red},
        breaklines=true,
}
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single][t]
This section contains my Makefile 2
Some lines are really toooooooooooooooo oooooooooooooooooo long
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]